# Symbol dependent inputs?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking to add notes to each symbol as my bias. I notice that once I switch to a different symbol, the bias I added is carried over. This is annoying. Could anyone tell me how to set it up so the bias notes I manually set would not be carried over to other symbols?

The upper right corner is the example of the indicator.
https://www.tradingview.com/x/cizX8aVP/

And this is the code:

`

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// You have to manually enter the notes

//@version=5
indicator("BIAS Notes", overlay = true)

textSize = input.string(size.normal, 'Text Size', [size.tiny, size.small, size.normal, size.large, size.huge], inline='txt')

Weekly = input.string("Unclear", "Weekly", options = ["Unclear", "Bullish", "Bearish"])
Daily = input.string("Unclear", "Daily", options = ["Unclear", "Bullish", "Bearish"])
H4 = input.string("Unclear", "4H", options = ["Unclear", "Bullish", "Bearish"])


Weekly_color = color.rgb(65, 154, 227)
Daily_color = color.rgb(65, 154, 227)
H4_color = color.rgb(65, 154, 227)

if Weekly == 'Bullish'
    Weekly_color := color.rgb(0, 152, 68)

if Weekly == 'Bearish'
    Weekly_color := color.rgb(176, 48, 48)

if Daily == 'Bullish'
    Daily_color := color.rgb(0, 152, 68)

if Daily == 'Bearish'
    Daily_color := color.rgb(176, 48, 48)

if H4 == 'Bullish'
    H4_color := color.rgb(52, 172, 114, 20)

if H4 == 'Bearish'
    H4_color := color.rgb(206, 62, 62)
    
var table = table.new(position=position.top_right, columns=2, rows=5, border_color = color.black, border_width = 1)
table.cell(table, 0, 0, 'BIAS NOTES', bgcolor = color.black, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
table.merge_cells(table, 0, 0, 1, 0)
table.cell(table, 0, 1, 'Weekly', bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
table.cell(table, 1, 1, text = Weekly, bgcolor = Weekly_color, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
table.cell(table, 0, 2, 'Daily', bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
table.cell(table, 1, 2, text = Daily, bgcolor = Daily_color, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
table.cell(table, 0, 3, '4H', bgcolor = color.gray, text_color = color.white, text_size= textSize)
table.cell(table, 1, 3, text = H4, bgcolor = H4_color, text_color = color.white, text_size = textSize)
```

`

I was expecting that once I set the bullish/bearish bias in the inputs, once I switch to another contract, the settings would not be carried over, so I can go over different contracts and set my bias for each contract. Right now when I set the bias, it keeps the bias settings, which makes this indicator useless.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you work in a layout. Structurally the layout is the base where you can draw, add indicators to etc. and the ticker you're referring to like "SPX" is just loaded into it.
The easiest way is - depending on your subscription - to store a layout like "SPX" with your indicator with your notes and if you want to switch to "DXY", you open up a separate layout for that.
Alternatively if you want to work within one layout, you'll have to do something like this, though ugly:

```
string text := na
if syminfo.tickerid == NASDAQ:AAPL
    text := "test 1"
else if syminfo.tickerid == NASDAQ:TSLA
    text := "test 2"
...
```

However you'll have to alter your code manually each time you want to update your notes because there are no dynamic inputs in pine script.
I suggest the first option.